# ¿Cómo evitar que el usuario elimine la aplicación o elimine los datos del dispositivo android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo una aplicación empresarial, la cual solo se instala en dispositivos autorizados, ahora lo que  necesito es que el usuario no pueda desinstalar la aplicación y que no  pueda borrar sus datos, similar a las aplicaciones de fabrica de `Google`. 
He probado colocando en el `Manifest.xml`:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" />
```

Pero eso me marca el siguiente error al momento de compilar:

> Permission is only granted to system app

Comment: La única forma de hacerlo es instalando la aplicación inicialmente como de sistema (usando las herramientas del fabricante o "rooteando" el móvil). Posteriores actualizaciones en la aplicación podrán instalarse sobre la inicial manteniendo los permisos. La caché son datos volátiles, nunca ha de asumirse que estarán ahí cuando los necesitemos, por lo que no puedes tampoco evitar que se borre su contenido, ni siquiera las aplicaciones de sistema pueden impedirlo. Por último, echa un vistazo a https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin

Answer (score 20, accepted):

En este caso las aplicaciones que vienen pre-instaladas tienen la característica que precisamente se comenta en el mensaje al tratar de usar el permiso:

> Permission is only granted to system app

**La única forma de evitar que el usuario desinstale tu aplicación es que esta sea creada como aplicación de sistema. Sin embargo es importante comentar que no puede ser desinstalada pero no puedes evitar que se puedan eliminar ciertos datos como bases de datos, cuentas, configuraciones, etc.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El proceso para crear una aplicación de sistema en Android esta documentado en varios lugares, pero es importante saber que pueden ser de dos tipos:

> - Aplicaciones instaladas en la partición del sistema, que pueden ser manipuladas por usuarios con permisos [ROOT](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_rooting).
> - Aplicaciones firmadas con la misma clave de firma que firmó el [firmware](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware).

La segunda opción es difícil de realizar para nosotros los desarrolladores ya que no tenemos acceso a llave con la que fue firmado el  [firmware](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware).

te recomiendo revisar:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1776095

---

Si deseas utilizar el permiso:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" />
```

**tu aplicación debe ser creada como aplicación de sistema**, revisa la documentación de este permiso:

> [android permission = "android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN) (Nivel de protección: firma) es un
>   permiso que debe tener una subclase DeviceAdminReceiver, para
>   garantizar que solo el sistema pueda interactuar con el receptor (no
>   se puede otorgar a ninguna aplicación este permiso). Esto evita que
>   otras aplicaciones abusen de la aplicación de administración de su
>   dispositivo.